# argument 1 passed must be instance of model in provider repository

Tags: php, laravel

i m working with team on project it was working fine with me , but i had to change my os.
after clone i have to update composer it gave me

```
Argument 1 passed to Jsdecena\Baserepo\BaseRepository::__construct() must b  
  e an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, instance of Illuminate  
  \Foundation\Application given, called in /home/amr/.composer/vendor/laravel  
  /installer/onlinestore/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/P  
  roviderRepository.php on line 208
```

it works fine with my coworkers
i hope someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i re-clone the repository and install composer instead of update it and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade the package version to exactly **"1.0"** instead of using latest version i.e **1.0.6** or **"^1.0"**

```
"jsdecena/baserepo": "1.0",
"jsdecena/mcpro": "1.1",
```

issue in github: https://github.com/jsdecena/baserepo/issues/9#issuecomment-536535380